# GNU Assembly Language: How to understand the stack pointer in recursive function (factorial calculation)

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, stack-memory

I try to understand the stack framework by the GAS, and a recursive function assembly case is shown here, as a 32-bit x86 program for Linux:

```
.section .data

.section .text

.globl _start
.globl factorial

_start:
    pushl $3
    call factorial
    popl %ebx
    movl %eax, %ebx
    movl $1, %eax
    int $0x80


.type factorial, @function
factorial:

    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    movl 8(%ebp), %eax

    cmpl $1, %eax
    je end_factorial

    decl %eax
    pushl %eax

    call factorial

    popl %ebx
    incl %ebx
    imul %ebx, %eax

end_factorial:
    movl %ebp, %esp
    popl %ebp
    ret
```

Architecture: x86-64 on Ubuntu 18.04 with GCC 7.5.
Build with

```
as -o test.o powertest.s --32
ld -o test test.o -m elf_i386
```

I have found some similar questions related to my question, but I am still stuck at the stack pointer move or pop/push back.

Referring to this case, the code finds the factorial of 3.
To my understanding, the pseudocode should be:

```
PUSH 3 -> PUSH RET -> PUSH EBP -> PUSH 2 -> PUSH RET -> PUSH EBP -> 
PUSH 1 -> POP EBP -> POP RET -> POP EBX ->POP EBP -> (Stuck here)
```

When the EAX iterates to 1, the internal EBP and RET is popped.

Then, within the function (EAX == 3), POP EBX should be popped.

However, according to the pseudocode above, I think maybe the EBP should be popped.

It really confuses me that the code really gets the correct result.

I have read some references, they said that the push and pop mush match with each other. Otherwise, the memory may crash.

My question is how the stack components in this case are popped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pseudo code was missing a `PUSH RET -> PUSH EBP` after the `PUSH 1`:

```
            PUSH 3 -> PUSH RET ->
PUSH EBP -> PUSH 2 -> PUSH RET ->
PUSH EBP -> PUSH 1 -> PUSH RET ->
PUSH EBP
```

At this point eax == 1 so it returns back up the call chain

```
POP EBP ->
POP RET -> POP EBX -> POP EBP ->
POP RET -> POP EBX -> POP EBP ->
POP RET -> POP EBX
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I miss the end_factorial block that can be executed for each eax iteration.